# Is the gloom shroom worth it?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I just bought the gloom shroom from twididinkies (crazy daves shop.) However while I play the fog levels I have noted its high sun cost (for the fog levels anyways) for the low range so I often have to use pumpkin to protect it so it doesn't get eaten. The only good thing is the area of effect range and the high damage. Is the gloom shroom really worth its price?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gloom shroom is one of the strongest plants in the game.  It is absolutely worth the price.

Pros:

- Extremely high DPS (4 hits per second)
- Hits ALL zombies in range, even full stacks
- Hits through papers, screen doors, and ladders
- Can attack zones behind it and in adjacent rows

Cons:

- Expensive (even more so during the day as you'll need coffee bean)
- Short range

If you plan 2 of them in rows 2 and 5, you can take out the majority of the zombies without issue.  You can supplement them with garlic to force zombies to move to a different row in order to protect your gloom shrooms better.  In the long run this costs you way less sun than having an equivalent amount of defense.  This also leaves you way more space to plant more suns or other defensive plants (like magnets, etc).

The short range is also mitigated by plating nuts in the other lanes to hold the zombies while the gloom shroom kills them.

The gloom shroom is so good that even with the additional cost of coffee bean its worthwhile to use during the day.  During night levels they're a no brainer.

Comment: What is the garlic? Remember, I'm only on the fog levels.

Comment: Oh and by the way, I don't know whats a coffee bean or what it looks like.

Comment: @MelonPult you'll get them eventually, though you may have to buy those from Dave's shop.  For now, just using pumpkins to protect them should be good enough.

Comment: I think since I've only seen crazy dave sell upgrade plants so I guess they are earned on the roof.

Comment: Rest assured, you'll get coffee bean after roof 5-3 and garlic after 5-5. Try being more defensive on your gloom shroom lines at the moment.

Comment: Wait so it looks like from your text that garlic moves zombies on other lanes and coffee bean wakes up mushrooms. Am I right?

Comment: @II if you tell me  what they do or if anyone tell me I might be able to accept the answer, or I can't accept it because I don't know what those plants are.

Comment: @MelonPult you got it right.  Garlic plants will move any zombie that takes a bite out of it to a neighboring lane, and coffee bean will let you use night time plants in the day time at a cost of 75 sun.

Comment: Also con: Vulnerable; best used *behind* a Wall-Nut or Tall-Nut.

Comment: @II already mentioned the vulnerable short range thing, right?

Comment: Oh and also plant the gloom shrooms in rows 2 and 4 on day and night levels, right? When you said rows 2 and 5, you were talking about the pool and fog levels right?